# “TypeError: iElement.autocomplete is not a function” in AngularJS 1.4.4 but no error in AngularJS 1.0.0

Tags: javascript, angularjs, autocomplete

I am trying to make an autocomplete using AngularJS without using any JQuery. I was following [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/vojtajina/JSkjP/12/). Here is the html code:

```
<div ng-app='MyModule'>
    <div ng-controller='DefaultCtrl'>
        <input auto-complete ui-items="names" ng-model="selected">
        selected = {{selected}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the controller and  directive:

```
function DefaultCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.names = ["john", "Bill", "Charlie"];
}

angular.module('MyModule', []).directive('autoComplete', function($defer) {
    return function(scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
        scope.$watch(iAttrs.uiItems, function(values) {
            iElement.autocomplete({
                source: values,
                select: function() {
                    setTimeout(function() {
                      iElement.trigger('input');
                    }, 0);
                }
            });

        }, true);
    };
});
```

The above code works perfectly with **angular-1.0.0**. But if I use **angular-1.4.4** it breaks and I get an error in my browser saying:`TypeError: iElement.autocomplete is not a function`. Is there any workaround for this in **angular-1.4.4**?

NOTE: I am trying to make it work **WITHOUT** using JQuery, angular-ui or any third party library.

Answer (score 0):

What you are following is an old example which uses an old version of angular. That's why it is not working.

Maybe wrapping the `iElement` with the `angular.element` and using the `triggerHandler`, it may work. 
Or if using jQuery try to wrap it with $ like:

```
$(iElement).trigger('input');
```

But my suggestion, even if it will work, is to switch to the angular-ui one. Simply much better, powerful and easier:

https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#%2Ftypeahead

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer. But I am trying to make it work **without** using JQuery, angular-ui or any other third party library. I have edited my question.

Comment: in my answer there is also a possible solution using only angular. Wrap your iElement with angular.element: `angular.element(iElement)` and use the triggerHandler for triggering the input:  http://api.jquery.com/triggerHandler/